# Sorting on hidden data

Tags: handsontable

Is it possible to have data in a Handsontable sorted by a field which is not displayed? I have a grid of data which I would like to display that contains a column called "sortOrder", but I don't want to display this.

The sorting needs to be done client side because events are coming in over web sockets and need to be reflected in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not showing the column then I assume you're not expecting the user to be able to manually sort by this hidden column. Therefore, why don't you simply sort your data array with native JS? At any point during execution you could have a function which sorts by this hidden column and then just don't render this in your Handson definition.

So yes, the answer is it is possible. The not showing of a column is as simple as defining the `columns` option and not including a column for this hidden value.

Comment: Thanks.  Its a shame that handsontable doesn't support this out of the box.

Comment: Well if you think about what a good JS library should be like, it almost makes sense that this isn't supported. Users always want a library to do most of the work for them but in reality, a good library is one that is very self-contained and does everything that the user wouldn't easily be able to do themselves. Sorting and manipulating data is definitely something Handson attempts to do, but sometimes doing some manipulations yourself using events that they provide ends up being the better solution :)

Comment: Another very important point is that OS is available for you to download, develop the functionality, and give back to the community what something like Hansontable will be giving you for free. Once you think of it that way you can see that it is not a shame that feature is not available OOB but a shame to develop the functionality and not share it :).